# How to create a JAR with only the class files needed by a given class

Tags: java, jar

I have a directory full of hundreds of class files that have been constructed by a previous compilation. Let's say I have a class which only depends upon a small subset of those generated class files.  Is it possible to create a JAR which only has the dependencies for the given class?

**EDIT:** Please note that I am not speaking of the library level dependencies (i.e. JARs).  When I refer to dependencies above, I am referring to the sort of dependency that results from class A calling class B.  Perhaps an example would be good.  Imagine I have the following classes in my project.

```
public class A {
    B bField;
}

public class B {
    C cField;
}

public class C {
    B bField;
}
```

Now imagine I want to build a JAR with class B, then the JAR would also need to include the class file for C because the one depends upon the other.  If I wanted to build a JAR from class A, then all three classes would be included.  Is there a way to examine this dependency chain and build a JAR with the result?

Comment: Maven has a "Shade" plugin that will do this.

Comment: Using a class-dependency analyzer to generate the list of dependencies may be the way to go. Then you can use the list of dependencies to build a JAR. Just doing a naive search, I found the following class-dependency analyzers: [dependency-analyzer.org](http://dependency-analyzer.org) and [depfind.sourceforge.net](http://depfind.sourceforge.net).

Comment: @viper could you please post how you were able to do this with Proguard? For me the dependent classes are coming empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several products can do this, including [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net).

The danger is that without exhaustive run-time analysis, or a good understanding of your code and any frameworks it uses, some classes may be missed if they've instantiated via reflection. Plugin systems, dependency injection, scripting, and so on can all interfere with the accuracy of static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can create a file with the list of classes that you do want to include and pass that file into the jar command. The details are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html).

Comment: The question is whether or not this can be done automatically.  I'd rather avoid maintaining dependency lists when the code already be necessity defines this chain.