# Create a JAR file from a set o class file

Tags: java, jar

I have some class files, but I have not correspondent java file, I would create a jar.
How can I create a jar file contains only some class files?

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: Here is a link to various [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). The section on "Deployment" has examples for creating jar files.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856996/how-to-create-a-jar-with-only-the-class-files-needed-by-a-given-class. The accepted answer has a link to a 3rd party product. I reopened the question given that there is no need to use a 3rd party product.

Comment: In the end, .jar files are only .zip files with an additional `metadata.inf` file. If you have 7zip, you can simply right-click a jar file, or open the .jar file with a zip file manager. There you see how the contents are ordered. (Same goes for new MS Office file formats like docx, xslx etc, and many more btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some class files, but I have not correspondent java file, I would create a jar. How can I create a jar file contains only some class files?

You can use this example:

```
jar cvf myJar.jar MyClass.class MyClass2.class
```